# php mail function has stopped working suddenly

Tags: php, function, email

First of all I know that there are serval topics like mine but i couldn't figure it out so i started this topic.
I just changed `$from` in this code  and again i undo it but after that mail function is not working i have tried error reporting but there was no error in it can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code ?

```
<?php
    // Check if button name "Submit" is active, do this 
    if(isset($_POST['send']) && $_POST['send'] == 'Send')
     {

        for($i=0;$i<=$_SESSION["count"];$i++)
        {
            if(isset($_REQUEST['checkbox'][$i]))
            {
                $set_id = $_REQUEST['checkbox'][$i];

                $sql_new=mysql_query(" UPDATE `article` SET  `editor`='SENT'  WHERE `id`='$set_id' ", $connection);
                $article=$_REQUEST['file'][$i];
                $TOmail=$_REQUEST['editoremail'][$i];
            }
        }

        $subject ="Dear Colleague,";
        $message = "Please Read & Edit this Paper : {$article}
                    \n\n
                    \n Thanking you 
                    \n----------------- 
                    \n
                    \n Editorial Office ";
        $to = $TOmail;
        $from = "jept.ir";
        $headers = "From:" . "{$from}";
        $mail=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers,$from);


        if(($sql_new) && ($mail)){
        $_SESSION["count"]="";
        echo "<div class='cleaner h30'></div>";
        echo "<b style='color:green;margin-left:10px;'>Article has sent to editor successfully!</b>";
        $sql_new='';
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"2;URL=editor.php\">";

         }
         else
         {
            echo "<div class='cleaner h30'></div>";
            echo "<b style='color:red;margin-left:10px;'>Something went wrong!</b>";
            $sql_new='';
            echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"2;URL=editor.php\">";                          
         }                      
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have closing " in `$message` variable + you added wrong five parameter to `mail()` function. Also your headers weren't exactly proper. I edited your `mail()` function and `$headers` with utf8 capability.

```
$subject = "Dear Colleague";
$message = "Please Read & Edit this Paper : {$article}
            \n\n
            \n Thanking you 
            \n----------------- 
            \n
            \n Editorial Office ";
$to = $TOmail;
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset = \"UTF-8\";\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Jept.ir <email@jept.ir>' . "\r\n";        
$mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: sorry my bad , i've missed it when i was posting in here .

Comment: accually I've found the problem that was from $to, it's getting a wrong email address, but away what you have done in headers make all of \n unusable !

Comment: Oh yeah I have added content-type text/html. Now you can use html in your mail which is quite comfortable.